# How to not "hide" Page when App Bar is open in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, appbar

I'm building a windows store apps, I'm using windows 8 and VS 2012.

I think my question is pretty simple but I can't find an answer anywhere..
I've added an AppBar at the bottom of my page and that's the code

```
  <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource EditAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource RemoveAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource AddAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource RefreshAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource HelpAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="Button_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Now the problem is that when the AppBar is Open the Page is "obscured" until I click again on the Page.

Is it possible to not obscured the page while AppBar is open?

Any help would be very appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

first remove the padding of appbar and your container has fix margin as well as height and width . try with below and not forgot to set property of image as content....

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
<shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Default" Opacity="1.0">
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
    <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
</shell:ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, but the App is not for Windows Phone but for Windows 8 PC/tablet.